# How to make a URL user friendly?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, opencart

I have some pages in my website which don't have user friendly URL. for eg.

`www.mysite.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=68&vendorId=Cookie%20Dough`

So I want to change it directly to `www.mysite.com/Cookie-Dough` by using .htaccess.
so far I have hard coded following code in my .htaccess.

`RewriteRule ^Cookie-Dough index.php?route=product/category&path=68&vendorId=Cookie%20Dough [NC,L]`

which is working fine. But the problem is my vendor ids can change, so I want it dynamic. suppose if I have another URL like

`www.mysite.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=68&vendorId=JELLY%20BEANZ` than I want it to be `www.mysite.com/JELLY-BEANZ`without hardcoding the code in .htaccess.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `/store` with your own subdirectory:

```
---.htaccess file start ----

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /store
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

# Added for non www queries
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www .%{HTTP_HOST}/store/$1 [R=301,L]
---.htaccess file ends ----
```

Comment: Please explain this shahid.

Comment: I know basics of it , I found this code way back to make friendly URL's!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?route=product/category&path=68&vendorId=$1%20$2 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite

```
/foo-bar
```

to

```
/ index.php?route=product/category&path=68&vendorId=foo%20bar
```